# Entity Framework map struct/complex type without model properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent, entity-framework-6

I have a 'model `struct`' which is internally a string, but is being used to somewhat similiar to a `GUID`.

```
public struct Token {

    private string _value;

    private Token(Guid uuid) {
        _value = Token.FromGuid(uuid);
    }

    public static Token FromGuid(Guid uuid) {
        // perform 'transformation'
        // stuff
        // return...
    }

    // other static methods to create a token...

}
```

How can I map this entity using **Entity Framework 6 Code First**? I'm aware that structs are not supported, but a *complex type* also doesn't seem applicable since the `class` doesn't contain any properties.

Comment: map in what sense. Show your desired usage. You want a Poco that has a property of this type ?  What did you try already?

Comment: 'You want a Poco that has a property of this type ?' Exactly. I need a 'globally unique' id which is random like the GUID, but url friendly.

Comment: and why not use a public string set/get and use your struct internally?  And why have you discounted a complex type?

Answer (score 3):

Structs are not a supported EF type. See [ef supported primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382832%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You will need to use a complex type instead.

- `modelBuilder.ComplexType<Details>();`
  or
- Data Annotation `[ComplexType]`

But consider the alternative using a string and managing the public get/set accordingly